# UITabBar keeps UIPickerView's bottom to display

Tags: iphone, uiview, uipickerview, uitabbar

I am trying to show the picker view immediately after the the `viewDidLoad` method get called. But, the `UITabBar` block some parts of picker view from displaying. How to bring the picker view to the front of the `UITabBar`? The pickerview is a `UIView` subclass. The code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pickerView = [[AllPickerView alloc] initWithdelegate:self];
    [self.pickerView showInView:self.view];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide tab bar while showing the picker view or can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.pickerView];
```

or if you want you can add it on `TabBarViewController`

```
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:...]; or 
[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:...];
```

Comment: Not the best idea. The pickerview blocks the top navigation bar. And it stays on the top. I want it comes from the bottom with animation.

Comment: You can animate it whatever you want using UIView animations

Answer (score 0):

Set frame properly

```
 [self.pickerView  setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.pickerView .bounds.size.height, self.pickerView .bounds.size.width, pickerView.bounds.size.height)];
```

Edit:

use add subview instead of showInView

```
[self.view addSubView:self.pickerView];
```

Comment: It's not working. The picker view comes from the bottom of the view.

Comment: [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:...] the pickerview shows on the top bloking the navigation bar. [self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:...] the pickerview shows in the tabbar subview not in the view controller's view.

Comment: @yongho : Use both and try